# Select specific cities from List

Tags: c#, console

I need to do this:

I have a list of museums and have a list of museums in which cities museums is free and open on friday. I need to select (write my console) only that city which has most free open museums on friday.

List:

```
List<People> cities = FreeOnFridayAction(museums);
```

As I mentioned before, list "cities" holds names of cities where is museums free on friday. now it shows this:
Klaipėda, Biržai, Biržai, Biržai, Vilnius.

What I need to do is to write on console which cities has most open free museums on friday and how much there is of them (At this point: Biržai and 3)

Comment: Let us help you in the same way you have posted the question!

Comment: Having a variable of type `List<People>` with the name `cities` does not make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, what is the class People andwhy does it mean city. You need something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(cities.Distinct().Count());
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", cities.Where(city=>city.IsOpenOnFriday).ToList()));
```

If you need more concrete answer please fedine more concrete question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a foreach loop to check all items in your list and inside the foreach block you can check if the city meeting your condition with an if statment

```
 foreach (ppl People in list)
        {

            if (People.visted == 5)
                Console.WriteLine(People.cityname);
        }
```